# StructuredDiscussions Extension for Semantic MediaWiki: Is it possible to make a link that creates a discussion page with a specified name?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I would like to use the [StructuredDiscussions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StructuredDiscussions) extension to create a discussion that is linked to a wiki page. Right now I have to go to Special Pages -> Enable Structured Discussions and enter the name of the discussion page I would like to create.

Now I would like to be able to embed a link on a wiki page that redirects to Enable Structured Discussions and ideally creates a page that has the format '[wiki page] Discussion' (maybe there is a way to pre-fill the form with the name of the page that linked me there?). Or maybe there is some kind of workaround for that.

I tried to find a way to make a form for creating a StructuredDiscussion page but it seems it's not possible to make a template for that.

Help is very appreciated. :)

Comment: Please share a link to your wiki or at least a link to the markup being used.